# Ionic framework - command 'ionic serve' returns 'multiple addresses available'

Tags: command-line, ionic-framework, localserver

First time ionic (and stackoverflow) user here.

I created a new project.

Now, I'm trying to view it in chrome via a local webserver by running the command 'ionic serve.'

I get a prompt that says:

```
Multiple addresses available.

Please select which address to use by entering its number from the list below:
 1) [IP address]
 2) localhost
Address Selection:
```

I can't seem to find what to enter for 'Address Selection.' Would it be my own local IP address?

Also, when I listed [IP address], I mean it was literally my local IP address.

Comment: Nevermind, just entering 'localhost' fixes it.

Comment: Why did you "enter" localhost? You can just type 2.

Comment: I don't think you experienced the freeze issue as described here, but just in case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26251899/ionic-framework-command-grunt-serve-returns-multiple-addresses-available-a

Comment: @RaymondCamden Because it was the first thing I did that worked.

Comment: @Dalie That looks similar. The same prompt came up with 'ionic serve', while they had the same prompt with 'grunt serve.'
Thanks for posting this. I'll look a little harder next time!

Answer (score 0):

If you choose localhost that will run locally and not be available outside of your machine. Choose the other IP to expose this service to the local network if you wish.

Comment: It's just a test project, so local is fine for now.
Thanks for catching that, though, I probably would have made that mistake if it was production code.

Comment: @Max Hi Max, I accidentally chose localhost and now it is remembered on this computer. How do I change this back to the first option?

Comment: @Chowza there is a `.ionic` folder at your `$HOME` location, Edit `ionic.config` file in that folder. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26328184/ionic-serve-displays-multiple-addresses-and-i-chose-wrong-one-how-to-change-ad

Answer (score -2):

Enter the option 1 or 2 value to run in browser