# ionic serve displays multiple addresses and I chose wrong one...How to change address that ionic serve uses?

Tags: ionic-framework

I used `ionic serve` and got the below response to which I did not think twice and selected `localhost`. However now I want to use option 1. Ionic has remembered my selection such that `ionic serve` never allows me to select anymore and uses `localhost`...

How can I change this so that ionic serve uses the first option?

```
Multiple addresses available.

Please select which address to use by entering its number from the list below:

 1) 192.168.2.10 (en0)
 2) localhost

Address Selection:
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use the `ionic address` command to update the selected address, which is available from Ionic 1.2.3.

Also, there is a file called `ionic.config` which you can modify with this setting. On Mac/ubuntu this file is at `~/.ionic`. On a PC it can be found at `c:/users/username/.ionic`. Inside you'll see something like this which you can edit the `ionicServeAddress` value.

```
{
  "ank": "...",
  "versionCheck": 1413143560174,
  "ionicServeAddress": "localhost"
}
```

Comment: you are freaking awesome dude! For people who come across this in the future, the location on my PC was `c:/users/___your_user_name___/.ionic`

Comment: mine was `c:/users/__username__/.ionic/ionic.config`.  I simply deleted the whole "ionicServeAdddress" property and ran `ionic serve` again to get the prompt back -- beautiful!!

Comment: Great to know how and where ionic saves this but the command 'ionic address' should be the accepted answer. It's Ionic's official answer to this question.

Comment: It didn't exist at the time this question was posted :)

Comment: could you add the documentation link about this config file?

Answer (score 38):

just type `ionic address` command and you get the option to select your IP address again.

OR

you can explicitly select your address and port when you run `ionic serve`

by using the `--address` and `--port` options. Like this:

`ionic serve --address IP_address --port port`

example : `ionic serve --address 192.168.1.129  --port 8101`

**Things to note**

- If you do not provide a port option with `--address` the       default port(8100) is used instead.
- Specifying address and port will only change the settings for that session. if you need to override saved settings, you should probably use the `ionic address` command instead.

Answer (score 4):

This has been fixed in version `0.6.1`

Update to the latest version by running `npm install -g generator-ionic` and then run `yo ionic` inside your current project and select `Y` when Yeoman asks if you would like to overwrite your `Gruntfile.js`

Comment: Great! Fix confirmed.